# How can I solve for the area under sine rotated 45 degrees?

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I'm interested in finding a method(s) for solving the area under a sine wave rotated 45 degrees.

I'm confident I could solve this problem analytically without too much trouble by writing out an algorithm in something such as Python. That's quite crude however, and would only be an approximation, no matter how close. I'm interested in trying to find an *exact* method. I'm still interested in approximating solutions however, exact is simply preferred.

It stands out to me that you could try to break it down by simply integrating for $y=x$ and then account for how sine affects it. The line described by $y=x$ will intersect the 45 degree sine wave for $ x = \pi n$

Because of this, I believe whenever $n$ is even, ( let's stick to natural numbers for a moment ) the effect of sine will "cancel" out, and it will simply be $\int x$ for $[0,n]$ . In the case that $n$ is odd, one would find the area to be represented by $\int_0^n x + \int_0^\pi \sin(x)$ .

Opening back up to all real numbers, you would determine whether you're on an odd or even interval, and then build off of that. It's tempting to assume you could do something like $\int x \pm \int \sin(x) $ but from what I can tell, this would be wrong. Try picking an x value such as $x = \frac{3\pi}{2}$ . That lies perfectly in between the intersection points of $y=x$ and the 45 degree sine wave. However, that vertical line doesn't intersect the point of the 45 degree sine wave where its slope $m=1$ . It becomes clear at this point then, you would be adding or subtracting the area for quarter a period in a sine wave, when visually you can see we don't have quarter the area of a sine wave's period. I haven't done much to get past this part of the problem.

Comment: Does it help to change to the equivalent equation 
$\enspace\displaystyle \int\limits_{\pi}^{y+\pi} \sin^2(\frac{t}{2})dt=\int\limits_0^x \sin^2(\frac{t}{2})dt\enspace$ to discribe the area ? (What I mean is that to work with only one function, here $\sin^2(\frac{t}{2})$, can be easier.)

Comment: I do not think that the curve you are dealing with is $y=\sin x$ rotated $45$ degrees counterclockwise.  It has more similarities to $y=\sin (\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}x)$ rotated 45 degrees counterclockwise, but it is not exactly that either.

Comment: @MatthewConroy Can you explain your reasoning? I went through a process to get $y - \sin(y) = \sin(x) + x$ , but it's certainly possible I was wrong. The process I took was out of scope for this question, hence why I treated it as a given what the representation for sine rotated 45 degrees was. It simply wasn't going to be reasonable to ask people to verify that to.

Comment: @AustinJenkins Before getting into more complicated aspects, have you tried plotting your curve and y=sin x together and looked at them? When I do this, it is clear to me that one is not a rotation of the other.  What do you see?

Comment: I took some time to look at it more closely in Demos, and it seems while they're definitely related, it's probably not an actual rotation. For sin(x), the distance from the origin to $[\pi,0]$ is obviously $\pi$ . After rotation, distance shouldn't be effected, but it has been. The distance became $\sqrt{ 2 * \pi^2 }$ . I'm going to have to revisit that part it seems.

Comment: You're welcome! Cheers.

Comment: @MatthewConroy In case you're interested, I think the way to actually show the rotation is likely $ l(x) = \sin(x) + x , h(x) = x - \sin(x) , k(x) = l(inverse h(x)) $ . $k(x)$ would represent the actual rotation.

Comment: It's also nicely represented parametrically by $x=ct-c\sin t, y=ct+c \sin t$, where $c=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.